# How Circular reference and Iterations works in Excel

Tags: excel, iteration

I am using SUM function with Circular reference.

For example :
Excel values -

```
A1 = 10, A2 = 20, A3 = 30, A4 = SUM(A1:A4)
```

I am getting A4 result as "6000".
Image reference : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7pBs.png

What is the logic behind it?

Currently I am working on a customer bug in Circular Reference.

Customer used more than one Circular reference.

Example :

`B1 = "=IF(B6>9,1,2)" , B2 = 3.6 , B3 = 5.1 , B4 = "=SUM(B1:B3)", B5 = "" , B6 = "=B2+3+SUM(B1:B6)*0.1"`

Image ref : [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiHgc.png

In this case how excel behaves?

Comment: When I try this with Excel 2016 I first get a message that I'm introducing a circular reference an then the value is 0 in "A4". So I guess it is a implementation detail.

Comment: We will get some value only if 'Enable iterative calculation' is enables in the Excel options.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is 60 when adding the first 3 fields, repeating that 100 times gives 6000

This only works if you enable 'Enable iterative calculation' under options.

[image]